# Getting error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.runtime.java.CitrusObjectFactory

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I have `cucumber.properties` file that contains following: `cucumber.api.java.ObjectFactory=cucumber.runtime.java.CitrusObjectFactory`

But looks like it cannot find this `class`. Could you please let me know, what did I miss?

Comment: Hi Friend, I request you to check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As Praveen mentioned please provide MCVE. Most likely class not found related issues are related to build path and how references are set to external libraries. Please refer: https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning and building project ? Restart the IDE as well and check again !